# How to tell the difference between the Canon 18-135mm and the STM version?

Tags: lens, canon

I am looking to buy the Canon 18-135mm IS STM lens off eBay, and want to know if there are any outside visual differences that I can look for to make sure I don't get ripped off and buy the non-STM version instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look towards the front element it will say STM:

[image: Example from Amazon]

Comment: Note, I don't feel like pulling out the [ol' red pen and circling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/236671) where it says STM. It is on the bottom.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Thank you! This is just what I was wanting.

Comment: @ChristopherSpencer You're welcome and welcome to the community. If you're satisfied with this answer, make sure to mark it as such.